# How can I install/enable the PHP 7.0 zip extension on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, apache, zip, ubuntu-14.04

When trying to use the ZipArchive class, I see the message `Class 'ZipArchive' not found`.
I searched online and it saw many people saying to install the zip extension using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

However, apt is unable to locate the `php7.0-zip` package:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-zip'
```

I'm using apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

**Edit**:
I've tried adding the PPA `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and running `sudo apt-get update`, but I still get the same result when trying to `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04 there is no PHP7 version included. So you have to add an external repo manually to get that versions.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

Then you can install that version. If you have already added that repo you should check if it's working.

Comment: Adding one thing to this after adding the repo. You need to run the update command.
`sudo apt-get update`

After that  `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`

hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately, even after adding that PPA and running `sudo apt-get update`, I still get the same error
`E: Unable to locate package php7.0-zip 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-zip'`